# How to write unit test for vue-treeselect using vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-treeselect

I want to write unit test on [vue-treeselect](https://github.com/riophae/vue-treeselect). I followed the testcases written in the [repository](https://github.com/riophae/vue-treeselect/tree/master/test/unit/specs). There they have taken wrapper.vm.forest.nodemap to find the options but when i try it is giving forest "***undefined***".

Does anyone have idea how to get wrapper.vm.forest in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I have used treeselect something like this

```
<treeselect
          v-model="selected"
          data-test="treeselect"
          :multiple="true"
          :options="options"
          placeholder
          value-consists-of="LEAF_PRIORITY"
          :required="true"
          :show-count="true"
          :default-expand-level="1"
        >
```

I gave data-test="treeselect" to find this component than in testcase used like this:

```
expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="tenants"]').vm.forest.selectedNodeIds).toEqual(["anything"]);
```